# how to calculate feature's discriminability

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, feature-selection

guys. we know that the feature we selected should be with some degree of discrimination. That is samples from the same class will have comparatively similar feature values, contrary to the samples from different classes. The question is how to measure this discrimination. Let's limit this question to logistic regression. Each dimension of logistic regression corresponds to one weight. What's the relation between the discrimination and weight?